# SimpleDateFormat parsing in Android

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a date time string into a date object. However, I keep getting the wrong date but I dont know why. Can you help me?

My code looks like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yy-HH:MM");
String test = serverEntry.getString("date") + "-" + serverEntry.getString("time");
String test2 = dateFormat.parse(test).toString();
```

An example run has these outputs:

```
test = "27.06.14-12:18" // as in 27th of June 2014, 12.18 (24-hours)
test2 = "Sat Jun 27 12:06:00 CEST 2015"
```

Comment: String test2 = dateFormat.parse(test).toString();

Comment: Yes you are right. However, it gives the same result - just tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MM` specifies month of the year and `mm` specifies minutes. So you need this instead:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy-HH:mm");
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm :D Are there a place where the formatting is defined?

Comment: Yes, in the JavaDoc. I added the link to my answer.